# (android) Why custom toolbar uses BaseTheme?

Tags: android, toolbar, appbar

I set BaseTheme's Actionbar as NoActionBar and i started making Toolbar in XML.

But i have a problem.

Beacause even though I set NoActionBar, The color of the toolbar i made is still BaseTheme's Color.

I don't know why this happens.

Also, I did not set up toolbar's theme

Why does it use still the same color when i set the NoActionBar of BaseTheme?

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.writeweight">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WriteWeight">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_dailyrecord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

values\theme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.WriteWeight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'll wait your answer.

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A theme is a collection of attributes that's applied to an entire app, activity, or view hierarchy—not just an individual view. When you apply a theme, every view in the app or activity applies each of the theme's attributes that it supports. Themes can also apply styles to non-view elements, such as the status bar and window background.

This is a documentation quote which describes that themes are inheritable by default to all **view** or **non-view** elements in your app, unless you hard-coded your own theme.

If you notice that in `manifest`, your `<activity>` tag is a child of `<application>` tag, and yet the activity inherits the theme set in the `<application>` this way and cascade this inheritance all the way down.

This is an advantage as it keeps the coherence of your app elements and the user experience accordingly.

You can check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) for further info.